# Hidden message embedded in image

Tags: visual, steganography

There is a hidden message embedded within the below image just below the graphic of Shadow the Hedgehog that cannot be viewed using a normal image viewer. Can you find it?

> [image: Nice try, didn't find it here either]

Hint 1:

> To find it, you need to use *pyrotechnics*.

Hint 2:

> The message is written in one specific font and begins with "I'm".

I'm looking for an answer that also clearly explains the trick I used to obscure the text and why it works. Bonus points for finding the user being referred to by the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using

> Adobe Fireworks

software, you can create layers even in ordinary .PNG file.

The text is hidden in such a layer:

> [image]

Switching to Layer 1, the text is revealed at last:

> [image]

Which means the hidden message is

> I'm Shadow Wizard, the ultimate life form!

And as for the bonus question...

> Well, that would be... me. :)

Explaining the hints:

- Hint 1:

  > pyrotechnics are also fireworks, so this led me to the software that should be used.
- Hint 2: didn't really need it, not familiar with that software, so just looked for the second layer and messed around until the message showed up.

Comment: This software uses PNG as its native format, in much the same way that Photoshop uses PSD and GIMP uses XCF. (It also has the option to save with a "double extension", much like ".tar.gz".) The software's data is in a proprietary format and is saved in space that is ignored by normal image viewers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will be useful, but after converting the image to text and searching a lot of insensible text, there was this information hidden in the file.

> [image]

Comment: It says "Adobe Fireworks CS6" and pyrotechnics are fireworks type things.